# How to find injected code in SQL?

Tags: web-application, php, sql-injection, backdoor

Recently one of my sites was hacked. The hacker used SQL injection to compromise the security. After getting SQL access he injected code in many places in the database. I cleaned up many of them. But I am still worried that it may contain any hidden backdoor.

How can I find such injected code?

Comment: Did you find the original problem, making SQL-injection possible at first place?

Comment: Yes. original problem is fixed. I just want to make sure he didn't put any backdoor inside db.

Comment: BTW, I have extracted all the codes in db and now manually checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest reviewing the connection settings for the DB as well as resetting any passwords and verifying any hostnames for users allowed to connect to the DB.  Also, be sure that you have run down the original source of the intrusion.  (If you have a query log, look for what other querys happened with the rogue queries, since SQL injection piggybacks on a valid query.)

The more complicated issue would be if you are hosting HTML content out of the DB in which case the attacker could have introduced pages that would allow for further injection, but such records would be very hard to find without doing a diff as you described.  This could also apply if they did any permission elevation within the system that is running on the DB.

There may be other things worth checking, but those are the immediate things that come to mind for generic ways that a SQL DB could remain compromised.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't trust any type of automated review - a single false negative, and the server will get popped again. Hopefully you have known-good backups from before the attack, otherwise it'll be hard to know what you can trust.

Comment: I have a sql dump of previous day. I can run a diff. But diff does not work well here.